# .find not returning full object

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup to scrape a page of call codes in our phone GWs. Using soup.find and soup.find_all doesn't return the full element I'm looking for. This is my first script using BeautifulSoup, so I may be overlooking something.

This is the block in the html I'm trying to pull

```
<tr class='styReportFooter'>
  <td align='center'><span class='styPageTitle'>Totals</span></td>
  <td align='center' id='column1' style='display:none;'><span 
class='styPageTitle'>1862</span></th>
  <td align='center' id='column2' style='display:none;'><span 
class='styPageTitle'>153</span></th>
  <td align='center' id='column3' style='display:none;'><span 
class='styPageTitle'>12</span></th>
</tr>
```

and my query

```
total = soup.find('tr', attrs={'class': 'styReportFooter'})
```

I expected to get the entire block, instead I get this:

```
<tr class="styReportFooter">
<td align="center"><span class="styPageTitle">Totals</span></td>
<td align="center" id="column1" style="display:none;"><span 
class="styPageTitle">1862</span></td></tr>
```

It grabs up through column 1 then skips to

Comment: Are you sure the first given block is the only occurrence? I know you talked about find_all but have you used that? What is the output you see and how does that compare to the output you want to see?

Comment: @Adam, I get the same result using find and find_all, I went through the entire page and this is the only time this class name is used.

Comment: @kindall i went to the website to double check the code, those lines are closed properly with /td, but the parsed code shows /th. Any idea why that would happen, or a way to compensate for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your parser to lxml. If the HTML is not  well-formed different parsers will treat it differently.

[Differences between parsers.](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""
<tr class='styReportFooter'>
  <td align='center'><span class='styPageTitle'>Totals</span></td>
  <td align='center' id='column1' style='display:none;'><span
class='styPageTitle'>1862</span></th>
  <td align='center' id='column2' style='display:none;'><span
class='styPageTitle'>153</span></th>
  <td align='center' id='column3' style='display:none;'><span
class='styPageTitle'>12</span></th>
</tr>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
total = soup.find('tr', attrs={'class': 'styReportFooter'})
print(total)
```

Output:

```
<tr class="styReportFooter">
<td align="center"><span class="styPageTitle">Totals</span></td>
<td align="center" id="column1" style="display:none;"><span class="styPageTitle">1862</span>
</td><td align="center" id="column2" style="display:none;"><span class="styPageTitle">153</span>
</td><td align="center" id="column3" style="display:none;"><span class="styPageTitle">12</span>
</td></tr>
```

If i were to use `soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')`above i would have got

```
<tr class="styReportFooter">
<td align="center"><span class="styPageTitle">Totals</span></td>
<td align="center" id="column1" style="display:none;"><span class="styPageTitle">1862</span></td></tr>
```

Comment: Ah, that fixed it! Thanks much, you guys are awesome, I'll have a read over the list of parsers. I spent two days bashing my head on this for two days.

Comment: @Scandelis All the best!